# jQTouch Screen Orientation

Tags: iphone, jqtouch, screen-orientation

I'm looking to lock the page orientation to portrait but can not find how to do this. I'm using jQTouch and developing for iPhone.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can with a web app, unless you lock the orientation with your iPhone, which locks the orientation of Safari.